# Apache 403 forbidden even after configuring Directory, file chmod and selinux settings

Tags: apache

my command

> wget localhost

returns

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)...::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-11-08 02:10:03 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

my apache home dir is /home/@@web/apache

httpd.conf Directory and index

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/home/@@web/apache/htdocs"

<Directory "/home/@@web/apache/">
    # Some comments
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Request all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
<IfModule>
```

and apache error log is shows

```
access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/@@web/apache') because 
search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

and I ran this to change selinux contexts

```
chmod -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/@@web/apache
```

which changed my files' selinux contexts to

```
unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Turn off SELinux and try again. It will confirm if it is SELinux or basic permissions.  Wait, shouldn't your `<Directory>` block be configured for "/home/@@web/apache/htdocs"?  Why allow access to "/home/@@web/apache/" ?  Your `DocumentRoot` is not set to that.

Comment: @Nic3500 Yeah, it was like that when I first installed apache. But I changed it trying to solve the problem. Should change my directory permissions. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..
Stupid mistake

I didn't give my user home directory auths.

```
chmod 755 /home/@@web
```

solved the problem.